# how to add zoom functionality to chart created by jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have drawn a XY chart using jfree. Now i want to add zoom functionality to it. This must be done using a slider at the bottom of the chart. How can i add zoom functionality, the likes of which is present in Windows Photo Viewer?

Also, i would like to show the current Y-value of the graph as a tooltip when the user hovers his mouse over the plotted line. I am not getting much ideas. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`XYPlot` *et al.* implement the [`Zoomable`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Zoomable.html) interface, which allows `ChartPanel` to control zooming. I'd think you could use these methods in your slider's `ChangeListener`.

> I would like to show the current Y-value of the graph as a tooltip…

You can enable tool tips, as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo).